# Consuming Yellow Pages.com using FSharp Type Providers

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I signed up for the yellow pages.com API program found here: https://publisher.yp.com/home.

I went to make a call like this and I am getting back JSON in the browser:
http://pubapi.atti.com/search-api/search/devapi/search?term=Jumbo+China+5&searchloc=6108+Falls+Of+Neuse+Rd+27609&format=json&key=ZZZZZZZZ

When I take the json results and put it into Json2CSharp, it renders fine.  When I try  and load it into a type provider:

type RestaurantListingJson = JsonProvider< @"http://pubapi.atti.com/search-api/search/devapi/search?term=Jumbo+China+5&searchloc=6108+Falls+Of+Neuse+Rd+27609&format=json&key=ZZZZZZZ">

I get a 400

Looking at fiddler, I see
"User agent is a required field"

Has anyone run into this before?  How do I add a user agent to a type provider?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of F# Data now always sends user agent and accept headers, so this should now work directly:

```
type RestaurantListingJson = JsonProvider<"http://pubapi.atti.com/search-api/search/devapi/search?term=Jumbo+China+5&searchloc=6108+Falls+Of+Neuse+Rd+27609&format=json&key=ZZZZZZZ">
```

Answer (score 4):

I have not created an account, so I could not try this - but if the error message says "user agent is a required field", then I guess that the service requires setting the `User-Agent` header of the HTTP request.

This is not supported in static parameters of the `JsonProvider`, so the best way to get this to work would be to download the sample JSON, save it to a local file (say `yp.json`) and then use that to create the type provider:

```
type Yp = JsonProvider<"yp.json">
```

To actually download some data (when you want to make a request), you can use `Http.RequestString` which takes `headers` - there you can specify any required headers including `User-Agent`:

```
let response = 
  Http.RequestString("http://httpbin.org/user-agent", headers=["user-agent", "test"])
```

Then you can load the data using `Yp.Parse(response)` (rather than using the `Load` method directly to request a URL which would not let you specify the header).

Comment: @JamieDixon - Regarding adding this as a static parameter - I think we cannot realistically add static parameters to support all possible access patterns. I think it should work for standard URLs, but when you need more, using a local file is a decent solution (IMO). Also, local files work better when you need to compile on a train :-)

Comment: Thanks Thomas Seems like another thing to add to the constructor of the TP. I think we are at 13+ and counting? :-).  BTW it is @jamie_dixon